# Registration redirecting even with validation errors

Tags: php, html

I have created a php registration page. Everything is running well. It shows an error when I leave text box empty.

However when I use the action method to redirect the registration page, it's always redirecting, both when I am writing something and when I'm not entering something in the text box.

I want that the page doesn't redirect when the field is empty. I use a boolean and the `break` method, but nothing is happening.

Can anyone help me here on this issue?

```
<html>  
 <?php
 include 'header.php';

 $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $passwordErr = $addErr = $phoneErr = "";

 $fullname = $email = $gender = $password = $address = $phone = "";
$flag = false;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
     break;
   $flag      
   } 
   else {
     $fullname = test_input($_POST["fullname"]);

   }


   if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
     $passwordErr = " password required";
  break;
   } 
   else {
     $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   break;
   } 
   else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }



   if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addErr = "Address required";
   break;
   } 
   else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $genderErr = "Gender is required";
   break;
   } else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
     $phoneErr = "phone no required";
   break;
   } else {
     $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
   }
} 
?>
<body>
<br>
<div class="regis_div" >
  <form name="myForm"   <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>  method="post" action="thanks.php" >

  <table class="table2" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="15" >
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3"><h1><center>User Registration Form</center></h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="291"> &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Full name:</td>
    <td width="150"><input type="text"  name="fullname"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
  <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Confirm Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="Confirmpassword"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Email Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" ></td>
    <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Gender:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</td>
        <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td height="80">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Address:</td>
    <td><textarea type="text" name="Address" class="address" rows="4" cols="20" ></textarea></td>

    <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $addErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
  <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Phone No:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><font size="2" color="red">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="regbtn2" type="submit" value="Submit" align="center" ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to describe.

Comment: when i am not writing anything in any text box and submitting the form the form is submitting successfully without any errors and redirecting to new page but i want a condition that  submit successfully only when the form is field .

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    break;
} else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "phone no required";
    break;
} else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
}
```

[`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) will only break out of `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do-while` and `switch` structures, not `if` statements.

It's also unclear exactly *which* script you believe should be handling your form submission:

```
<form name="myForm" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>  method="post" action="thanks.php" >
```

If the script you posted above is named `form.php`, then the above line will produce the following (invalid) markup:

```
<form name="myForm" form.php method="post" action="thanks.php" >
```

When submitted, execution will immediately flow to `thanks.php` and none of your PHP error checking (as posted above) will run.  If you want the code you posted above to run, you should change that form tag to this:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
```

Then, once you're satisfied that your submission has no errors, you can redirect the user to a new page:

```
header('Location: thanks.php');
```

You should also note that, when that line is executed, you will loose access to all of your existing POST data, so you must do something with it if you wish to preserve it *before* redirecting with a header.

However, there's quite a few issues with your code.

```
if (empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    break;   // Already mentioned this line will have no effect
    $flag    // Why is this line here?  
}
```

How will you know, using your current structure, if *any* error was encountered? It would have to look like this:

```
if(isset($nameErr) || isset($passwordErr) || isset($emailErr) || ...)
```

You can simplify that with an array:

```
if (empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
    $errors['name'] = "Name is required";
    // ...
}

// ...

if(count($errors)) {
    // Some error occurred, don't redirect
} else {
    // ... do something with POST data ...
    header('Location: thanks.php');
    exit; // Always exit or die after issuing a header redirect
}
```

And the associated markup:

```
<?php if(isset($errors['name'])) { ?>
<span class="error">
    <font size="2" color="red">* 
        <?php echo $errors['name']; ?>
    </font> <!-- Don't forget to close all of your opened HTML tags -->
</span>
<?php } ?>
```